# How to use zf2 hasRoute() in a view

Tags: view, routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to develop an index view that renders links using something like:

```
echo "<a href=";
echo $this->url($route, array('action' => $action, 'id' =>$id));
echo ">$targetName</a>";
```

where `$route`, `$action`, `$id` and `$targetName` are all drawn from a database.

I can’t rely on the data for the `$route` variable and when `$route` doesn't match a viable route, the whole page crashes.  I'd like use an `if` statement to evaluate the existence of a route, but I haven't found the right solution.  I think that I’m looking for something like:

```
if ( hasRoute($this->url($route, array('action' => $action, 'id' =>$id))) ) {
   // render something
} else {
  // render something different
}
```

However, I can’t determine from reading the documents how to use the `hasRoute()` function properly.  The simple code above causes `Fatal error: Call to undefined function hasRoute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `hasRoute` view helper in Zend Framework, but you can create one ([documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html)).

First, you need create view helper class, which has router as dependency:

```php
<?php
// file module/Application/View/Helper/HasRoute.php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

final class HasRoute extends AbstractHelper
{
    /** @var SimpleRouteStack */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @param SimpleRouteStack $router
     */
    public function __construct(SimpleRouteStack $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $routeName
     * @return bool
     */
    public function __invoke($routeName)
    {
        return $this->router->hasRoute($routeName);
    }
}
```

Then you need a factory for this view helper, which creates new instance of our helper and injects the router:

```php
<?php
// file module/Application/Factory/View/Helper/HasRouteFactory.php

namespace Application\Factory\View\Helper;

use Application\View\Helper\HasRoute;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class HasRouteFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return HasRoute
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $router = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('router');

        return new HasRoute($router);
    }
}
```

And finaly you need to register this new view helper to view helper plugin manager:

```php
// Application module configuration file in module/Application/config/module.config.php
// ...
'view_helpers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'hasRoute' => \Application\Factory\View\Helper\HasRouteFactory::class,
    ],
],
// ...
```

You can then call this view helper in any template:

```php
<?php
    if ($this->hasRoute('home')) {
        // do something if there is route with name 'home' defined
    }
?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  I was getting confused over documentation for the hasRoute method of the SimpleRouteStack. This seems like a common enough issue that a hasRoute helper should be part of the zf2 package.  It would also be nice to be able to evaluate the existence of the entire route including parameters, and not just the route name.